# Swipe to refresh issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

i added the hide fragment to the first fragment,and then it is showing the second fragment with out any problem , but now when i use swipe to refresh app crash.. pleeeease help me to fix this issue.

to hide the first fragment iam using this code:

public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment, String tag) {

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
Fragment fragment2 = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);

if (fragment != fragment2) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_enter, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.left_enter, R.anim.right_out);
    transaction.hide(fragment2);
    transaction.add(R.id.frameContainer,someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and for swipe to refresh in the Activity i´m using this code :

```
 private void swipe_swipeRefresh() {
        String fragment = null;
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);
        if (currentFragment instanceof FragmentHome) {
            fragment = "FragmentHome";
            }
        if (currentFragment instanceof BlogFragment) {
            fragment = "BlogFragment";
        }
      Handler handler = new Handler();
        final String finalFragment = null;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SettingsMain.reload(HomeActivity.this, finalFragment);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
             SettingsMain.hideDilog();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

SettingsMain.reload(HomeActivity.this, finalFragment); this line its coming from :

```
  public static void reload(Context context, String tag) {
        Fragment frg;
        FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

        frg = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        final FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

      ft.detach(frg);
      ft.attach(frg);
      ft.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `finalFragment` in `SettingsMain.reload(HomeActivity.this, finalFragment);` is `null` in your code because of the following line:

```
    final String finalFragment = null;
```

Next, inside the `reload()` method `frg = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);` is used. But the `tag` here is null, and so it cannot find the fragment. Resulting in `frg` being `null`. Detaching and attaching it will cause a crash because `frg` is `null`.

To fix it, try to change the line to

```
final String finalFragment = fragment;
```